# Use SignalR to notify connected clients of new login to Web.API

Tags: oauth-2.0, signalr, asp.net-web-api2, signalr-hub

I have an exiting set of APIs developed with ASP.NET Web API 2. Currently users need to authenticate before using most of the APIs (a few are public). Here is my scaled down OAuthProvider.

```
public class MyOAuthProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
  // Validation of user name and password takes place here
  // Code not show for brevity
  // If user is validated issue then issue them a JWT token 

  ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager, "JWT");

  var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, null);

  context.Validated(ticket);
}
```

In separate application I have experimented with SignalR and have a Hub class that takes the connectionId and userName of a user and stores it to an in-memory Dictionary named `connectionDictionary`.

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public static Dictionary<string,string> connectionDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        connectionDictionary.Add(Context.ConnectionId, Context.User.Identity.Name);
        return base.OnConnected();
    }
}
```

How do I go about joining these together so that when a user authenticates with the API, their connectionId and userName are stored in the Dictionary? The idea being that once a user has logged in I will notify all other connected clients.

Comment: I don' t know if I have understood correctly, do you want to connect to the SignalR hub using the authentication token and then use the identity info in the token to register the user in the in-memory dictionary?